# Swift - UITableView Cell animation on selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, transform, uiviewanimation

I am animating a tableView cell selection from with the didSelectRow at method, which is working. My code is as follows :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                
                cell!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.97, y: 0.97)
                
            }, completion: { finished in
                
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                    
                    cell!.transform = .identity
                }
                
            })

}
```

I'd like to be able to put this in the custom class file for the cell but don't know where to start. Is this possible ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use func ***setSelected(_ :animated:)***

First, you will have to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

suppose I created a Class name `TempTableViewCell`, In this, we do have a predefined function `override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)`.

Here **Selected** is the value for if the cell is selected or not. So you can have your code in this function like below.

Example

```
    class TempTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.97, y: 0.97)
            }, completion: { finished in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                    self.transform = .identity
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
}
```

And to use it in the cell follow the below code,

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: TempTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
```